# User Count for Hour

Tags: rdbms, amazon-redshift

I need to find the count of the user in different time
eg:

table:

```
    start_time             |  end_time           |   user_id 
    ----------------------------------------------------------
  1)  2014-11-25 01:23:00  | 2014-11-25 06:37:01 |   254
  2)  2014-11-25 01:54L33  | 2014-11-25 02:25:31 |   365
  3)  2014-11-25 01:55:36  | 2014-11-25 02:26:32 |   547
  4)  2014-11-25 05:16:21  |                     |   485
  5)  2014-11-25 05:29:03  | 2014-11-25 06:32:46 |   123
```

Required Result:

```
time  |  count
--------------
1     |  3
5     |  3
```

The user who is signed in for the particular interval should be calculated in the count for the interval hours
 for eg: the user 254 was logged in at **1:23** and logged out at **06:37**. the count should be in all the 1,2,3,4,5,6 hrs.

**reply me if the explanation is not clear.**

thanks in advance

Comment: Are your interval hours based only on the "hour" field? For example, user 254 was actually there for a duration of 5:14:01, which is more than 5 hours, yet only in 5 distinct hours "by the clock".

Comment: What does the blank value in row 4 signify and how should it impact results? How does the input map to the output -- is it a count of user_id against the number of clock hours between start_time and end_time? Why do the results have a total count of 6, whereas there are only 5 input rows? More information please.

Comment: @JohnR The 4th row is still active not yet logged out.  The result count is 6 because at hour 1, 3 Users were active and in hr 5, 3Users were active. next if the user logged out in 5:59:59 he should come under hr 5.

Comment: Technically it might be possible with some window function partition on user and then using this temp table to query per hour. However, I think that logically this is less interesting, as in hours that the user is logged in, but does nothing are not really important. Why not log every event the user is generating and then count distinct on this table?

Comment: @JohnR changed the first row date as 25 from 24

Answer (score 0):

Here's a query that works, but it might not be the most efficient.

```
-- Count how many of each count quantity appears
select qty, count(*)
from
(-- Count the number of different hours for each user
  select user_id, count(*) as qty -- Don't need user_id here, but helps debugging
  from
  ( -- List every hour+user combination
    select distinct hour, user_id
    from
    (-- List every hours over the period of interest
     select '2014-11-24 00:00:00'::timestamp + generate_series(0,48)*interval '1 hour' as hour) periods
     join flow ON (start_time < hour + interval '1 hour'
                   AND end_time > hour)
  ) hours
  group by hours.user_id
) user_count
group by qty
```

You'll have to adjust the number of hours (48) to cover the range of interest.

Basically it works this way:

- Create a series of hours of interest (assume clock hours rather than user hours)
- List one line per user-hour combination
- Group by user, to get a count of the number of hours in which each user participated
- Group by the hour count, and see how many of each count was used

Comment: Darn! I tried it on Postgresql, but didn't try it on Redshift directly. A table with hourly timestamps could take its place, though.

Comment: Mmm, `generate_series()` works sometimes, but Redshift doesn't seem to want to do a JOIN to the generated data.

Comment: Is there any other way to retrieve the result?

Comment: I have experimented with generate_series() in Redshift. It is partially supported, but fails when I try to JOIN against it. As mentioned, a table with hourly timestamps could take its place. Please note that the query would get quite slow with lots of entries, so multi-step approach (using intermediate tables) might perform better.